# Angular 8 - How to mock a subject returning from a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, subject

This is the service part:

```
@Injectable()
export class PinnedTileStateService {
    private pinnedTileStateSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject();

    public getPinnedTileState(): Subject<number> {
        if (this.pinnedTileStateSubject) {
            return this.pinnedTileStateSubject;
        }
    }
}
```

This is component part:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.pinnedTileStateService.getPinnedTileState().subscribe((pinnedTileId) => {          
               //anything          
        });
    }
```

I want to test the ngOnInit() method in the .spec.ts file. I have tried a couple of ways like mocking a subject but not succeeded.

Can I have help, how I can test the ngOnInit getPinnedTileState method which is returning subject?

Thanks much
/S

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
spyOn(pinnedTileStateService,'getPinnedTileState').and.returnValue(Observable.of(// whatever shall be emited));
```

If you want to test the onInit behavior you have to set the spy in an beforeEach block since you want to set it during your component initialization.